# get value from content type B, in a view of content type A

Tags: 7, views

i have a content type named songs. among other fields, it has a field named title of the song, which has as its field type the Node reference. i also have a second content type named songsTitles which keeps all songs' metadata, where there is for instance the duration of the song, the producer, etc. how can i retrieve in a view that i have created for the content type songs, instead of the node reference value, for each song, its duration instead? I would prefer to do it via the Views gui, since whatever i tried with code was not successful.

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve information linked through ER fields you have to add the Relationship for the ER field.

The Relationship will open new options you can add to your Views.

You will be able to add the **Duration** Field to your Views after you add the Relationship. That field will use the Relationship by default (it wouldn't work without it).